# What would they say after a sneeze in the 1950’s in Rio?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões

My grandma learned Portuguese in Rio in early 1950’s, and years later when anyone sneezed she’d respond in Portuguese.

I can’t remember her words now, but it’s not any of the words from other questions that I checked...

Also, if you sneezed a 2nd or 3rd time she’d say “outra vez, outra vez.”

Would anyone happen to know if they used to say something different that long ago?

Comment: Olá Tricia, bem-vinda. I made an edition to your question to try to improve it. If you don't like it or prefer to have it different, just [edit](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/5572/edit) your question. You can see the changes by clicking the "[edited X hours ago](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/posts/5572/revisions)" link in the middle-bottom of your question. :)

Comment: Tricia, what are the words you found and ruled out? I suppose "santinho" would be one of them. But if you let us know all of them then it will help us find the one you want. And don't worry about buchering spelling: we got it and fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

- Born and raised in Rio, the usual comment I would hear after someone sneezed was, and still is, "saúde".  Saúde translates as "health" and the person who says it is expressing a wish of "good health".
- Less frequently one might hear "Deus te abençoe" ("God bless you")
- In 21st Century Portugal I've heard "santinho".  ("little saint") which you hardly ever hear in Brazil.

Comment: I've heard (from my Brazilian grandparents perhaps) the expression "Deus te crie" ("May God create you") for that effect. It is a funny expression to use.

Comment: @Piovezan  "Deus te crie" is translated as "May God raise you".   "Criar" means traise, breed, bring up, in addition to "create".

Comment: Indeed, that is a better translation. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score -1):

I know by my grandmother that, if someone sneezes, they say *Blessing* for the first two times, but at the third time, they say *It's a cold!* (*É gripe!*).

Comment: Wellington, I believe you tried to commend, since you only translated English–Portuguese, but you wrote it as an answer,

Comment: Wellingnton, eles diziam mesmo "blessing"? O que importante é o que eles (os cariocas?) diziam em português. Se traduzes como "blessing", imagino que fosse "Deus te abençoe", mas isto sou eu a imaginar, porque "blessing" significa ’benção’, que eu nunca ouvi dizer a quem espirra.

Comment: @Jacinto Talvez o Wellington tenha querido dizer "Bless you", que dito rápido se assemelha a "Blessing".